# Trying to create an Image in java for a button but the image does not show up

Tags: java

```
private Image getButtonIcon(int counter){
        String imagePath = arrPrograms.get(counter).getIconPath();
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath));
        return image;
    }
```

imagePath variable looks like this at the moment: C:\Files\Photos\btn1.png.
The code for the button will look like this:

`dyButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(getButtonIcon(counter)));`

Edit: I got past the NullPointerException but now my file is not showing.

```
private void getButtonIconint counter(){
        try {
            String imagePath = arrPrograms.get(counter).getIconPath();
            FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
            FileInputStream(");
            Image image = new Image(inputstream);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
```

Code for button:

```
getButtonIcon();
dyButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```

The variable for the image is created in the class

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` should be used to get resources, not arbitrary files. Resources are usually files inside your resources folder in the IDE, which, when the program's jar is created, are placed inside the jar and read from there.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That actually helps a lot thank you.

Answer (score 0):

getClass is returning null then. Explicitly state the class name such as ShowImage.class.getResourceAsStream